# How to transfer data from a waterfalldialog to another?

Tags: c#, botframework

I am working on a bot framework project (C# - Bot Framework v4) which contains at least 2 dialogs. I want to transfer informations that I've created (not from the user) from a first dialog to another one. How can I do it ?

I tried to set the second parameter of the BeginDialogAsync function but it was empty on the arrival.

EDIT :

I have a first dialog (SignInDialog) which is used to connect the user with OAuthPrompt. When the user is connected, in the same class, I will then handle his intent with the Dispatcher (Microsoft) and LuisRecognizer, to tell if I have to use QnA or LUIS.

What I am trying to do is to call a specific dialog located in another Dialog class (PersonalInfoDialog), according to the user's intent. But whenever I pass some arguments to the `BeginDialogAsync` method, I don't find a way to get it from the destination dialog.

**SignInDialog class**

```
        private async Task<DialogTurnResult> PromptStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(OAuthPrompt), null, cancellationToken);
        }

        private async Task<DialogTurnResult> DispatchStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {

            var tokenResponse = (TokenResponse)stepContext.Result;
            if (tokenResponse != null)
            {

                var recognizerResult = await BotServices.Dispatch.RecognizeAsync(stepContext.Context, cancellationToken);

                var topIntent = recognizerResult.GetTopScoringIntent();

                var intent = topIntent.intent;

                switch (intent)
                {

                    case "CASE_1":
                        return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(PersonalInfoDialog), recognizerResult, cancellationToken);

                    case "CASE_2":
                        ...
                    default:
                        Logger.LogInformation($"Dispatch unrecognized intent: {intent}.");
                        break;
                }


            }

            return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync(null, cancellationToken);
        }
```

**PersonalInfoDialog class**

Here, in debug mode, test is null.

```
    private async Task<DialogTurnResult> PromptStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var test = stepContext.Options as LuisResult;
        return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(OAuthPrompt), null, cancellationToken);
    }
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why do you want to transfer it between dialogs? Why not just continue the current dialog with the information, until it's no longer needed, then swap dialogs? What kind of information are we talking about?

Comment: I added more informations on my original post. My goal here is to assign responsibilities to dialogs. I want for example, PersonalInfoDialog to handle dialogs on personal infos, etc... but with data that comes from the SignInDialog - with the Dispatcher. I hope I am clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly and you really have no other options to transfer the data in one Waterfall-Dialog:

You could use state property accessors to store/ load the data. 
In the Docs you find a example. Have a look at the `UserProfile`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-state?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp

And for more information I recommend the Doc article about states: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-state?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

Comment: Thank you, I think it will be useful.